# How to fix flickering/jittering of Skia-rendered canvas objects during GLFW window resizing?

Tags: c++, rendering, render, glfw, skia

I've been working on a project that involves Skia and GLFW for rendering. When I attempt to resize a GLFW window containing a basic rectangle object rendered using Skia, the object experiences flickering / jittering. Here's the source code for reference:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "include/core/SkCanvas.h"
#include "include/core/SkPaint.h"
#include "include/core/SkRect.h"
#include "include/core/SkSurface.h"
#include "include/gpu/GrDirectContext.h"

SkCanvas* canvas;
SkImageInfo info;
int width, height;
GLFWwindow* window;
sk_sp<SkSurface> surface;

SkPaint getPaint(SkColor s) { SkPaint paint; paint.setColor(s); return paint; }

void SetSurfaceAndCanvas() {
    info = SkImageInfo::Make(width, height, SkColorType::kRGBA_8888_SkColorType, SkAlphaType::kPremul_SkAlphaType);
    surface = SkSurfaces::Raster(info);
    canvas = surface->getCanvas();
    canvas->translate(0.0f, height);
    canvas->scale(1.0f, -1.0f);
}
void Draw() {

    canvas->drawRect(SkRect::MakeXYWH(0, 0, width, height), getPaint(SK_ColorWHITE));
    canvas->drawRect(SkRect::MakeXYWH(0, 0, 250, 250), getPaint(SK_ColorRED));

    if (auto dContext = GrAsDirectContext(canvas->recordingContext())) { dContext->flushAndSubmit(); }
    std::vector<uint32_t> pixels(width * height * 4);
    surface->readPixels(info, pixels.data(), width * sizeof(uint32_t), 0, 0);
    glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.data());
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

void frame_buffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* fwindow, int w, int h) {
    width = w; height = h;
    SetSurfaceAndCanvas();
    Draw();
}

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Skia Test", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &(width), &(height));
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, frame_buffer_size_callback);

    SetSurfaceAndCanvas();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) { 
        Draw();
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

[Here's a gif of the object flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge3cI.gif)

System Details: Apple M1 Pro, Ventura 13.5.1

Command used to run the code:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -w -g -I/Users/vasanth/skia -L/Users/vasanth/skia/out/RTTI -framework Metal -framework AppKit -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -std=c++17 -lskia -lglfw3 sample.cpp -o out
```

I attempted to address the flickering issue by following the suggestion in this [post](https://discourse.glfw.org/t/canvas-jitter-flicker-when-resizing-with-multithreaded-render-loop/2188/3). Specifically, I set the window's resizable attribute to `false` at the beginning of the resize callback and reverted it to `true` at the end. However, this approach did not resolve the problem for me.

Can someone please help me with what am missing here?